# Using old eclipse version (2020-06), installing plugins fails

Tags: eclipse, ide, osgi, equinox

I have researched this error quite a bit already, but could not find a solution yet.

Due to compatibility reasons with some software we are developing, we need to use Eclipse IDE version 2020-06.
Unfortunately, this version seems to use an old equinox framework version, which does not support the algorithm most plugins use for signing nowadays.

Error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.rcp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.cdt,7.8.0.63129.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\me~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3792878232785362905.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\me~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3792878232785362905.jar
```

Error from log:

```
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-03-24 11:50:21.996
!MESSAGE Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonarlint.eclipse.feature,7.8.0.63129.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 2 2023-03-24 11:50:21.996
!MESSAGE Error reading signed content:C:\Users\me~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4976703525857637395.jar
!STACK 0
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\me~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4976703525857637395.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.SignatureVerifier.verifyContent(SignatureVerifier.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.SignatureVerifier.verify(SignatureVerifier.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.SignatureVerifier.close(SignatureVerifier.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.artifact.repository.processing.ProcessingStep.close(ProcessingStep.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.checksum.MessageDigestProcessingStep.close(MessageDigestProcessingStep.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.artifact.repository.processing.ProcessingStep.close(ProcessingStep.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.checksum.MessageDigestProcessingStep.close(MessageDigestProcessingStep.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.artifact.repository.processing.ProcessingStep.close(ProcessingStep.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.artifact.repository.processing.ZipVerifierStep.close(ZipVerifierStep.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.reportStatus(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No algorithm found for 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.PKCS7Processor.findEncryption(PKCS7Processor.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.PKCS7Processor.processSignerInfos(PKCS7Processor.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.PKCS7Processor.<init>(PKCS7Processor.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.processSigner(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.process(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleFile.initializeSignedContent(SignedBundleFile.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:223)
    ... 19 more
```

I have already found the following links on the internet where this error is discussed, however the solution seems to be to upgrade to a newer version of eclipse, which is not possible for us.

Link 1: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1754
Link 2: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572034

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue in older versions of eclipse, e.g. my version of 2020-06?

Comment: Exactly what compatability issues are restricting you to 2020-06? Generally you can use the current version of Eclipse to develop for any Java or Eclipse release.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the issue is sadly. We have found that the RCP/RAP application we are not developing does not start when launched from eclipse 2020-09 onward. Or better said, it does not seem to respect the plugins/features specified at launch and instead it seems to to include all of them, which crashes the application. Could be something with eclipse running on java 11 from there on. If there is another way to just use a newer version of eclipse, I would rather gladly use that

Comment: You can p2.mirror the repo and unsign the plugins or resign them with p2.process task.

Comment: Hello Peter Kirschner, would you be willing to write a full answer so I can accept it? Ideally I want a solution that actually works and is not just a hack like mine

Comment: I had the same issue. I changed the jarsigner to be from jdk11 instead of jdk17 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried using jdk17 but still the same error. Or do you mean something else, just the jarsigner in a different version?

Answer (score -2):

The Eclipse version I use in the company is also 2020.06.

In order to solve the devstyle installation problem, I searched frantically for answers online, and finally I found the keyword tool p2 here.

After 8 hours of working, I finally have the solution.

I installed devstyle through a script.

Before running the script, the `commons-httpclient-3.1.0.jar` must be downloaded and placed in the `./eclipse/dropins/` folder so that devstyle will need it during the installation process.

Then run the script in the `eclipse root folder` where has ecplisec.exe.

The following is the `script.bat`:

```
eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository https://downloads.genuitec.com/downloads/products/devstyle/updates/ds20200720 -repository https://downloads.genuitec.com/downloads/products/codetogether/updates/ct20200716 -installIUs com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group,com.genuitec.eclipse.codetogether.feature.feature.group

echo Press any key to exit
pause >nul
```

Here's the explanation:

- Install the devstyle plugin by starting eclipse's built-in tool p2
- Download the appropriate versions of devstyle and codetogether by specifying the URL of the remote repository genuitec

  - For finding the appropriate version of devstyle, you can refer to this Delivery Log: https://www.genuitec.com/products/devstyle/deliverylog/
  - Regarding finding a suitable version of codetogether, I didn't find it's delivery log, so I could only find dates similar to devstyle’s.